# Why isn't require('./') the same thing as require('./index') from inside a module that has an index.js?

Tags: node.js

Been a way from Node for a bit and am finding myself confused about something I thought I understood:

From outside a module that has an `index.js`, if I `require('path/to/module')`, that `index.js` is consulted for that module's `exports`.

Now, I've got a situation where I'm working *within* such a module, and am trying to make references relative to the module's own `index.js`:

```
// index.js
exports.find_tests = require('./lib/find_tests');

// test.js
require('./').find_tests  // does not work
require('./index').find_tests  // works
```

I thought the first variant (`require('./').find_tests`) would work. Am I totally off base? I've got no `main` entry in `package.json`.

- Accessing `require('./')` yields is an empty object. What is it?
- `require('./index')` is `exports` in `index.js`.

Comment: @JonathanLonowski: No `main` setting. And `require.resolve('./')` resolves to `path/to/module/test.js`.

Comment: I suppose that answers it? But why does it resolve like that?

Comment: And how do I get my "desired" behavior, that I expected. Did I imagine this behavior?

Comment: what version of node are you using?

Comment: I'm on version 0.10.13

Comment: try `require(__dirname);`

Comment: I would ask you to post find_tests and also the actual output of the require statement. Work/Does not work is not helpful in pinpointing the problem.

Comment: Hey, looks like I DO have a `main` in `package.json` :(. Yikes. First time using `npm init` and I didn't look carefully enough at it. Sorry about that. Feel free to answer and I'll vote-up/accept, first come first serve.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure on the "why" that it doesn't work as expected, but I can tell you that if you `require('./.')`, it will work as expected.